# In dataframe: delete the paranthesis and everything within them in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, where a column has parentheses . I want to keep the content of the column, but delete everything inside the parentheses as below. Then add a constant text called "data" to it.

```
col1
counties(17) - cities(8)

I tried df['col1']=df['col1'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

this command is outputting only counties

My desired output is

```
 counties - cities data
```

Answer (score 0):

You are your expression is replacing everything with `""`? You should replace with `" data"` so as to get the result shown above.

Change

```
df['col1']=df['col1'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")
```

to

```
df['col1']=df['col1'].str.replace(r"\(.*\)", " data")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses the `re` module under the hood, so you regex must respect it and can use all its features. Here you want a non greedy match for the parenthesed word (the shorter) so you should use `df['col1'].str.replace(r"\(.*?\)","")`. If you want to add `" data"` it ends in:

```
df['col1'] = df.col1.str.replace(r'\(.*?\)', '') + ' data'
```